# Attributes as radio boxes, access to $product methods

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm just starting out with WooCommerce and hitting one mental block out of the gate. I see this whole web of template files that I'm wrapping my head around, but there are a few situations where I'd love to be able to just access the full `$product` object, methods and all, and just write my own template code.

This is playing out right now with the variable product attributes dropdown. Rather than a `select` I'd like radios with labels to make it easy to style them. Ideally I'd just grab the attributes from the `$product` object and write some HTML in a loop, but when I `print_r($product)` all I get is the slug of the product.

I noticed that in `wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options()` there's a call to `$product->get_variation_attributes()`, but I can't access that myself.

Any helpful tips for somebody at this stage with WooCommerce? Any suggestions around how to access the main `$product` object and template functions are preferred over copy/paste situations.

Comment: There was a plugin for this, but it had stopped working the last time I tried. not radio buttons, but there is [this script](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Convert-Select-List-To-A-Option-Picker.html) that I have thought about using in my own themes, but just haven't had the time. There is also the [Product Swatches](http://www.woothemes.com/products/variation-swatches-and-photos/) plugin which is already complete.

Comment: The plugin seems to not even create labels or use classes, so not super useful for styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WC_Product_Factory` class and then call function `get_product(ID)` to access the main `$product` object

### Example

```
$_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();
$product = $_pf->get_product($product_id);
```

You can then use all the function calls as listed in their api: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html